# Line chart with shaded areas

Tags: python

I tried to make a line chart while having shaded areas to indicate anomalies (recessions in this case). The `rate` is the variable for the line chart. I created a dummy variable, `normal`, to indicate if it is normal or not. I want the bar chart to be grey every period when `normal = 1`, similar to [this chart](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEB_enUS812US812&biw=1920&bih=949&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=QyTvW-aXPI_AsAXj3LzwCA&q=GDP%20during%20recession&oq=GDP%20during%20recession&gs_l=img.3..0i8i30j0i24l2.11621.17018..17252...6.0..0.175.2658.15j11......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0j0i67j0i10j0i30.C52utcUIqoE&safe=active&ssui=on#imgrc=jmlI_WadGZm4kM:).

This is my code so far. It is very different from what I desired. I wonder if someone can help me out.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'rate' : [90,40,30,30,30,25,25,20,15,10],
 'group' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
 'normal' : [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0]})

ax = df[['group','rate']].plot()
df[['group','normal']].plot(kind = 'bar',secondary_y = True, ax = ax)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, and based on the question you linked, you could just find your `group` values where `normal == 1`, and use `ax.vline` to draw a thick line at each of those points. For example:

```
ax = df.set_index('group')['rate'].plot()
x = df.loc[df.normal == 1, 'group']
for i in x:
    ax.axvline(i, color='gray', alpha = 0.5, linewidth=30)

plt.show()
```

[image]